# Remove search results indexed pages on Google

Tags: catalogsearch, seo, robots.txt, no-index

Google Search console is indexing thousands of Magento search results like these :
[image: Indexed pages in Google Search Console]

How do I get rid of these pages and avoid Google to show it in the search results ?

Will avoiding these URLs in robots.txt from getting crawled will remove them ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your robos.txt file

User-agent: *
Disallow: /*results?q=